# How to find the current value in this circuit?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, current-measurement, ohms-law

Here is the question i am getting how to proceed after finding the voltage

[image]

My attempt :

[image]

Next part of solution:

[image]

Comment: This is the fourth homework problem you've dumped on us in just over a day with no real effort to solve it yourself. You've calculated a voltage. What can you do with it? Do you know Ohm's Law? KCL?

Comment: I have calculated the voltage to solve in this way ,and i have added the solution that i attempted, i appriciate you help but if i ask a question that does not mean i am here to ask help for homework ,and i am trying to clear my concept with taking help of people who are good in this subject like you. But i try my best but sometime i find i get stuck in easy questions like this , and i will keep that in mind next time .

Comment: 12A is not the right answer?

Comment: @G36 i have calculated the voltage and then as all elements are connected in parallel so i have calculated current across 5 ohm register . Can you please tell me Which part is not correct .

Comment: But for me your solution is correct.  I just ask if you know the right answer?

Comment: Ohh sorry , yes thats the cirrect answer i checked